# Express web server deployed to prod but GET returns a timeout error

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, dart

I have a server that is running Windows 10. I created an Express project using this [repo](https://github.com/seanpmaxwell/express-generator-typescript). I ran in development mode just fine and I now want to deploy to production. I followed the instructions to do so:

- Check for linting errors: `npm run lint`
- Build the project for production: `npm run build`
- Run the production build: `npm start`

However, when I try to send a `GET` request to the IP address of the server, I get a connection timed out error. Was I supposed to do other things to prepare for deploying to production? Do I need to specify a port number? I'm relatively new to web server development, so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I am sending the request through a Flutter app:

```
  void test() async {    
    var url = Uri.http('ServerIPAddress');

    try {
      var response = await http.get(url);
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('ERROR: $e');
      }
    }
  }
```

Note: this is all on an internal network. It is not exposed to the public internet.

Comment: Try: `var url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/');`

Comment: @julemand101 this returns a `connection refused` error. Not sure if this will work because I am on one PC and the web server is a different PC.

Comment: How are you running the web server on the other PC? Are you sure there are no Firewall that blocks you? Does it work if you visit the site using a normal web browser?

Comment: @julemand101 on the web server, `localhost:3000` was working fine when I was deploying as a development environment. I now want to run this as a **production** environment. Are you sure it should still be `localhost:3000` for a **production** environment?

Comment: Ok, I can see in the source code that it seems to use port 8081 by default when running with default production settings. Can you try that?

Comment: @julemand101 Ah that was it. Specifically, it was `ServerIPAddress:8081`. Go ahead and write it as an answer if you'd like and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The express-generator-typescript generates three different environment files by default which each defines some options for running in the different modes. You can find the different default profiles here:
https://github.com/seanpmaxwell/express-generator-typescript/tree/master/lib/project-files/env

For port number, these are the ones it will use by default:

- 3000 *(development)*
- 8081 *(production)*
- 4000 *(test)*

For connecting in Dart, I would recommend making use of `Uri.parse` instead of `Uri.http` because it does make it a lot easier since the latter is a bit more complicated to use.

So something like the following for connecting to a production running server if using the default profiles:

```dart
var url = Uri.parse('http://<IP_OR_DOMAIN_TO_SERVER>:8081/');
```

Should be noted that in "real" production, you would not have this instance public but might instead have it forwarded though a proxy which can have HTTPS and run on port 443. E.g using nginx.

Answer (score 0):

in order to create simple http server with nodejs + Express:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Then you can run in your browser like: http://localhost:3000/

For running in a server, please search how to allow port in firewall. For CentOS:

```bash
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```